# XSLT modify attributes when condition is true

Tags: xml, xslt, transformation

I've this XML File and want to do some changes:

- exchange `P_ARTICLE_PARTNR` with `P_ARTICLE_ERPNR` when `P_ARTICLE_PARTTYPE="1"`
- every part element should have the same child element like the first part element

I didn' manage to change the property `P_ARTICLE_PARTNR` in my template `<xsl:template match="/partsmanagement/part/@P_ARTICLE_PARTTYPE[.='1']">` that matches the condition.

The second template `<xsl:template match="part[not(freeproperty/@P_ARTICLE_FREE_DATA_DESCRIPTION[.='value1'])]">`  deletes all ohter child elements from `part`.

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="transform.xsl"?>
<partsmanagement>
    <part P_ARTICLE_PARTTYPE="1" P_ARTICLE_PARTNR="0090.0006" P_ARTICLE_ERPNR="1009150" >
        <freeproperty P_ARTICLE_FREE_DATA_DESCRIPTION="value1" pos="20"/>
        <freeproperty P_ARTICLE_FREE_DATA_DESCRIPTION="value2" pos="21"/>
        <freeproperty P_ARTICLE_FREE_DATA_DESCRIPTION="value3" pos="41" P_ARTICLE_FREE_DATA_VALUE="value4"/>
    </part>
        <part P_ARTICLE_PARTTYPE="1" P_ARTICLE_PARTNR="0090.00068" P_ARTICLE_ERPNR="1009153">
        <freeproperty P_ARTICLE_FREE_DATA_DESCRIPTION="value1" pos="20"/>
        <freeproperty P_ARTICLE_FREE_DATA_DESCRIPTION="value2" pos="21"/>
    </part>
    <part P_ARTICLE_PARTTYPE="1" P_ARTICLE_PARTNR="0090.00069" P_ARTICLE_ERPNR="1009154">
        <freeproperty P_ARTICLE_FREE_DATA_DESCRIPTION="value98" pos="99"/>
        <freeproperty P_ARTICLE_FREE_DATA_DESCRIPTION="value3" pos="41"/>
    </part>
    <part P_ARTICLE_PARTTYPE="2" P_ARTICLE_PARTNR="0090.00069" P_ARTICLE_ERPNR="1009156">
            <freeproperty P_ARTICLE_FREE_DATA_DESCRIPTION="value98" pos="99"/>
    </part>
</partsmanagement>
```

With this XSL I tried to do the job, but it isn't working like expected.

When I change `<xsl:attribute name="{name()}">` to `<xsl:attribute name="P_ARTICLE_PARTNR">` the matching property is deleted and all others are not changed.

**XSL**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<!--Identity template,
provides default behavior that copies all content into the output -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

 <!--for element part with parttype = 1 --> 
<xsl:template match="/partsmanagement/part/@P_ARTICLE_PARTTYPE[.='1']">
 <xsl:attribute name="{name()}"> <xsl:value-of select="../@P_ARTICLE_ERPNR"/></xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

 <!--for freeproperty != value1 --> 
<xsl:template match="part[not(freeproperty/@P_ARTICLE_FREE_DATA_DESCRIPTION[.='value1'])]">
  <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>    
  </xsl:copy>  
    <freeproperty P_ARTICLE_FREE_DATA_DESCRIPTION="value1" pos="20"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

***Output XML***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?><?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="transform.xsl"?>
<partsmanagement>
    <part P_ARTICLE_PARTTYPE="1009150" P_ARTICLE_PARTNR="0090.0006" P_ARTICLE_ERPNR="1009150">
        <freeproperty P_ARTICLE_FREE_DATA_DESCRIPTION="value1" pos="20"></freeproperty>
        <freeproperty P_ARTICLE_FREE_DATA_DESCRIPTION="value2" pos="21"></freeproperty>
        <freeproperty P_ARTICLE_FREE_DATA_DESCRIPTION="value3" pos="41" P_ARTICLE_FREE_DATA_VALUE="value4"></freeproperty>
    </part>
        <part P_ARTICLE_PARTTYPE="1009153" P_ARTICLE_PARTNR="0090.00068" P_ARTICLE_ERPNR="1009153">
        <freeproperty P_ARTICLE_FREE_DATA_DESCRIPTION="value1" pos="20"></freeproperty>
        <freeproperty P_ARTICLE_FREE_DATA_DESCRIPTION="value2" pos="21"></freeproperty>
    </part>
    <part P_ARTICLE_PARTTYPE="1009154" P_ARTICLE_PARTNR="0090.00069" P_ARTICLE_ERPNR="1009154" />
                <freeproperty P_ARTICLE_FREE_DATA_DESCRIPTION="value1" pos="20" />
    <part P_ARTICLE_PARTTYPE="2" P_ARTICLE_PARTNR="0090.00069" P_ARTICLE_ERPNR="1009156" />
                <freeproperty P_ARTICLE_FREE_DATA_DESCRIPTION="value1" pos="20" />
</partsmanagement>
```

Hopefully somebody can help or give a hint?!
Thx

Comment: While asking an XSLT question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Well-formed input XML.
(2) Your logic, and XSLT stylesheet that tries to implement it.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample XML in the #1 above.
(4) XSLT processor and its conformance with the XSLT standards: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, or 4.0.